How to declare variables in PHP 8.3
in php 7.3. i did the following.
  $TitelString =    $_GET["TitelString"];
   If (!$TitelString) $TitelString="";
   $AuteurString =  $_GET["AuteurString"];
   If (!$AuteurString) $AuteurString="";
   $JaarString =  $_GET["JaarString"];
   If (!$JaarString) $JaarString="";

Now i'm migrating to 8.3 and i got errors which says :
Warning: Undefined variable $TitelString in D:\xampp\htdocs\fb\ltvg-1\ltvg-3.php on line 43
Warning: Undefined array key "AuteurString" in D:\xampp\htdocs\fb\ltvg-1\ltvg-3.php on line 44
Warning: Undefined array key "JaarString" in D:\xampp\htdocs\fb\ltvg-1\ltvg-3.php on line 46
I did try....
const $TitelString;
const $AuteurString = "";
const $JaarString="";


but it doesn't help
I searched on the internet, but it is not clear for me, what i now must do. I think it's easy...
Thanks,
Fred

You can use the ?: or ?? ternary operators.... use this guide and search for terms "??" and "?:" to find useful links for each.

Does this answer your question? Reference Guide: What does this symbol mean in PHP? (PHP Syntax)

I have use now ?? And it works… Thanks.

Use the null coalescing operator (??). It is available as of PHP 7.0.
This should work:
$TitelString  =  $_GET["TitelString"]  ?? '';
$AuteurString =  $_GET["AuteurString"] ?? '';
$JaarString   =  $_GET["JaarString"]   ?? '';

Before PHP 7.0, the ternary operator (?:) shall be used in conjunction with isset():
$TitelString  = isset($_GET["TitelString"])  ? $_GET["TitelString"]  : '';
$AuteurString = isset($_GET["AuteurString"]) ? $_GET["AuteurString"] : '';
$JaarString   = isset($_GET["JaarString"])   ? $_GET["JaarString"]   : '';

